# Request method 'GET' not supported. Why am I getting this error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I can't sign in to the site.Gives an error message. Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
I don't seem to have forgotten anything...The user registers successfully, but he cannot authorize. Tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Сlass WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            //Доступ только для не зарегистрированных пользователей
            .antMatchers("/","/index","/login","/registration").permitAll()
            //Доступ только для пользователей с ролью Администратор
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/blog").hasRole("USER")
            //Все остальные страницы требуют аутентификации
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            //Настройка для входа в систему
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            //Перенарпавление на главную страницу после успешного входа
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
}

@Autowired
protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**",
            "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**","/vendor/**","/fonts/**").anyRequest();
}
}
```

Class UserService

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
public UserRepository userRepository;
@Autowired
public RoleRepository roleRepository;
@Autowired
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Пользователь не найден");
    }
    return user;
}

public User findUserById(Long userId) {
    Optional<User> userFromDb = userRepository.findById(userId);
    return userFromDb.orElse(new User());
}

public List<User> allUsers() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}

public boolean saveUser(User user) {
    User userFromDB = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

    if (userFromDB != null) {
        return false;
    }

    user.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(new Role(1L, "ROLE_USER")));
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    userRepository.save(user);
    return true;
}

public boolean deleteUser(Long userId) {
    if (userRepository.findById(userId).isPresent()) {
        userRepository.deleteById(userId);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Class InputController

```
  @Controller
  public class InputController {

   //@GetMapping("/login")
   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String login(){
    return "login";
  }
  }
```

Login.html

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row main-form">
     <form class="" method="post" action="/login" modelAttribute="userForm">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Ваш Логин</label>
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                           <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Введите ваш логин"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Пароль</label>
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Введите ваш пароль"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group ">
            <input type="submit" value="Войти"id="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button" />
        </div>

        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
```

It seems that I wrote everything correctly, I don't understand what the problem is...

Comment: Include the details of the request that _causes_ that error.

Comment: you have a single button that sends a `post` request and a single method that expects a `get` - why do you think it should work? Here is nice [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-method-not-supported-405) about your problem

Comment: instead of guesswork, please post your full spring debug logs, and also the logs from the request in the webbrowser from the development console (F12 -> network)

Answer (score 2):

I reproduced your setup, and the 405 Method Not Allowed is caused by `.anyRequest()` in your posted code. By adding that at the end of your `web.ignoring()` of `WebSecurity`, you are instructing Spring Security's filter chain to ignore all requests. The 405 specifically comes from the fact that without Spring Security (since it is ignored for any request), you have implemented a GET /login, but not a POST /login in your application.

The topic of [HttpFirewall](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#servlet-httpfirewall) on the Spring Security docs may be of help to you.

Comment: If you remove `.anyRequest()`, does it solve your problem? If so, would you mind accepting the answer? Thanks.

Comment: if i delete .anyRequest(), then I get error 999. I tried then adding in  web.ignoring() "/error", but then it turns out a bunch of bugs. For example styles are not applied or upon successful authentication, the place of the main page opens the style file css in the browser

Comment: Can you be more specific about where you receive the 999? Is the posted login.html the entire file or did you omit part of it?

Answer (score -3):

I assume you are getting the error when attempting to navigate to the login page. /login is the default login processing URL and Spring expects it to be a POST. This can be changed with formLogin().loginProcessingUrl() but I don't suspect you want to do that. Change your get mapping, your ant matcher, and .loginPage("/login") to use something like /loginPage.

Comment: No, I get an error when I already enter my username and password and press the login button

Comment: Spring Security uses `GET /login` to retrieve the login form. This is provided automatically by Spring Security in a basic format and can be replaced exactly as OP demonstrated.

Comment: I don't quite understand what is wrong with me in this case